# How to run localhost or local website within Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, javascript, web, localhost, presentations

I have a demo coming up and I kind of want to show off different Javascript applications within the presentation. I was wondering if there was a way to run localhost, or web applications locally, within Powerpoint or another presentation-slide software?

If anybody has any other recommendations for creating slide presentations that allow web applications, they are also welcome! I'm just particularly curious if this is possible.

I've been perusing different things and I saw someone make an iFrame slideshow. I might consider that but I'm still curious if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck,this is exactly what you want.Very simple and dont need any iframe stuff.

[follow the instructions here!!!](http://www.labnol.org/software/insert-webpages-in-powerpoint-presentations/5108/)

Video :[Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU8ZIO-egf4)

Answer (score 2):

Shyam Pillai's free LiveWeb addin makes it fairly simple to embed a browser instance on a PPT slide and point it at any URL you like, internet or local file.  http://skp.mvps.org